# How to fire a bullet in the direction of finger swipe in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working on a game in corona. I want to fire a bullet when a user swipes their finger on an object. The further he swipes, the further the the bullet should go. I worked on this and on tap event the bullet is fired, there are two functions start projectile and game loop, start projectile is used to fire projectile and game loop is used to translate the weapon, but I can't understand how to aim for the target using finger swipe. Please give me any suggestions, thanks...
Code for what has been achieved so far is below

```
local function startprojectile(event)     
gameIsActive=true
local firetimer
local getobj=event.target
local getxloc=getobj.x
local getyloc=getobj.y
local function firenow()
if gameIsActive=false then
timer.cancel(firetimer)
firetimer=nil
else
local bullet=display.newImageRect("object.png",50,60);
bullet.x=getxloc-50; bullet.y=getyloc-50
bullet.type=bullet1
physics.addBody(bullet,{isSensor=true})
weaponGroup:insert(bullet)
end
gameIsActive=false
end
firetimer.timer.performWithDelay(650,firenow)
end

local function gameloop()                 
local i
for i=weaponGroup.numChildren,1,-1 do
local weapon=weaponGroup[i]
if weapon ~=nil and weapon.x ~=nil
then 
weapon:translate(-20,0)
end
end
```

Comment: Can you share what you achieved so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the angle that the bullet should be fired by using the built in lua function

```
startX, startY = player.x, player.y
dir = math.atan2(( swipeY - player.y ), ( swipeX - player.x ))
bulletDx = bullet.speed * math.cos(dir)
bulletDy = bullet.speed * math.sin(dir)
table.insert( bullet, { x = startX, y = startY, dx = bulletDx, dy = bulletDy } )
```

You can change the variable from swipe Y to whatever Corona uses (I don't code with it).
I'm assuming you know how to move the bullet, but if not,

```
for i, v in ipairs( bullet ) do
    bullet.x = bullet.x + bullet.dx * dt
    bullet.y = bullet.y + bullet.dy * dt
end
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where in my code i have to put the code you suggested because i am new to corona... thanks

Comment: Like I said, I don't know corona, but I would put it in my function that fires bullets. Then put that in a function that detects where the finger pressed. Probably something like: `corona.getX()` or something like that.